# Intersections preserved by inverses as a special case of similar fact about injective maps

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

It is true that for injective functions $f: X \to Y$ that $f(A \cap B) = f(A) \cap f(B)$ for all $A, B \subset X$. Moreover, for *any* function $f: X \to Y$ we have that $f^{-1}(A \cap B) = f^{-1}(A) \cap f^{-1}(B)$. I am trying to recognize the second fact as a special case of the first but am struggling. (I am aware that it can be straightforwardly proved otherwise.)

First to be more precise, above we are actually writing $f(A)$ as a shorthand for the image of $A$ under the function $f_{\bullet}:\mathcal{P}(X) \to \mathcal{P}(Y)$ which sends $A \mapsto \{y~|~\exists x \in A~:~f(x)=y\}$.

Then for the inverse $f^{-1}: Y \to \mathcal{P}(X)$, the analagous function $f^{-1}_{\bullet}$ is of type $\mathcal{P}(Y) \to \mathcal{P}\left(\mathcal{P}(X)\right)$, so it seems that applying the first fact to $f^{-1}$ (which we can since $f^{-1}$ is injective) gives a different statement than from what we are looking for. Is it something like we postcompose with the function sending $W \mapsto \cup_{w \in W} w$ ? (To be honest that last sentence was me stringing together words that sound right I don't actually know.)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, composing with the union map $U: {\cal P}({\cal P}(X) \to {\cal P}(X)$ does not suffice. So far, you get that
$f^{-1}_{\bullet} : \mathcal{P}(Y) \to \mathcal{P}\left(\mathcal{P}(X)\right)$ satisfies
$$
f^{-1}_{\bullet}(A \cap B) = f^{-1}_{\bullet}(A) \cap f^{-1}_{\bullet}(B)
$$
whence
$$
U(f^{-1}_{\bullet}(A \cap B)) = U(f^{-1}_{\bullet}(A) \cap f^{-1}_{\bullet}(B))
$$
Now we have
$$
U\bigr(f^{-1}_{\bullet}(A \cap B)\bigl) = U\bigr(\{ f^{-1}(c) \mid c \in A \cap B \}\bigl) = f^{-1}(A \cap B ) 
$$
and
$$
U\bigl(f^{-1}_{\bullet}(A) \cap f^{-1}_{\bullet}(B)\bigr) = U\bigl(\{ f^{-1}(c) \mid c \in A \} \cap \{ f^{-1}(c) \mid c \in B \}\bigr)\\
$$
The problem now is that the union map does not preserve intersections. For instance, if ${\cal A} = \bigl\{\{0,1\}\bigr\}$ and ${\cal B} = \bigl\{\{0\}\bigr\}$, then $U({\cal A}) = \{0,1\}$, $U({\cal B}) = \{0\}$,
$U ({\cal A}) \cap U({\cal B}) =  \{0\}$ but $U ({\cal A} \cap {\cal B}) = \emptyset$.

Comment: Mhm, but in the case of $M \in f^{-1}_{\bullet}(A)$ and $N \in f^{-1}_{\bullet}(B)$ either $M = N$ or $M \cap N = \emptyset$, so this must be the relevant condition.